# How to define the default value of a Slider widget on ipywidgets?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

On a Jupyter Notebook and using ipywidgets I can create sliders using the compact version

```
import ipywidgets as ip
def f(x):
    print(x)
ip.interact(f, x = (0, 1, 1))
```

The slider's default value is 0 but I would like to make it 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The widget abbreviations (using tuples to request sliders, etc.) only expose a small subset of the options that can be passed to a widget. Default values come from the default value in the function definition if available, or the center of the range if not. If you don't want to change the signature of your existing function to give it a default argument, you have two options to specify the initial value:

1. Wrap your function in another one that specifies defaults:

   ```
   def f(x, y):
       print(x, y)

   @interact(x=(0, 5), y=(-1.,3.))
   def g(x=1, y=2.0):
       return f(x, y)
   ```
2. instantiate a Widget directly and specify the `value` attribute, instead of relying on the abbreviations:

   ```
   w = widgets.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=1)
   interact(f, x=w)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Setting a default value in the function definition should work:

```py
import ipywidgets as ip
def f(x=1):
    print(x)
ip.interact(f, x = (0, 1, 1))
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, though that forces me to reorder my function inputs such that all with default values are at the end of the function declaration! Ideally I would have the default value on the widget declaration. but your solution helped me! Thank you

Comment: this works because of the `x=1` default argument in `f`, not because of the 3rd `1` in the tuple for `x` in the `interact` call.