# Telling IPython interact widget to ignore self argument in OOP

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use the IPython interact widget for a particular method in one of my classes. I would like it to ignore the `self` & `colour` arguments, and only adjust the `i` argument, but it insists that `self` is a bonafide argument too.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143237/how-to-define-the-default-value-of-a-slider-widget-on-ipywidgets), but neither method (using `fixed` on  `self` or pre-loading `self` into the method with `partial`) is appropriate in this case.

```
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact,fixed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Profile():
'''self.stages is a list of lists'''
    @interact(i=(0,5,1),colour=fixed(DEFAULT_COLOR))
    def plot_stages(self, i, colour):
        plt.plot(self.stages[i], color=colour)
```

This returns an error:
`ValueError: cannot find widget or abbreviation for argument: 'self'`

So how does one tell `interact` to ignore the `self` argument?

Comment: " but it insists that self is a bonafide argument too." It is right.

Comment: So then how would one get around this problem @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, does someone find an anwser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an “outer” function that takes the `self` and the constant arguments. Inside that define an “inner” function that takes only the interactive arguments as parameters and can access `self` and the constant arguments from the outer scope.

```py
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DEFAULT_COLOR = 'r'
class Profile():
    '''self.stages is a list of lists'''
    stages = [[-1, 1, -1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 10, 100], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

    def plot_stages(self, colour):
        def _plot_stages(i):
            plt.plot(self.stages[i], color=colour)

        interact(_plot_stages, i=(0, 4, 1))

p = Profile()
p.plot_stages(DEFAULT_COLOR)
```