# LineCollection, PatchCollection redrawing

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to have a Jupyter notebook with a matplotlib plot in which a `LineCollection` and a `PatchCollection` (of circles) can be changed by a slider:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, CircleCollection, PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider, Layout
%matplotlib notebook
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
lines = LineCollection(np.array([[[0,0],[1,1]]]))
circles = PatchCollection([Circle((.5,.5),.5)])
ax.add_collection(lines)
ax.add_collection(circles)
#lines.set_segments([[[0,1],[1,0]]])
#circles.set_paths([Circle((.5,.5),.1)])
interact(lambda s: circles.set_paths([Circle((.5,.5),s)]),
     s = FloatSlider(min = 0, max = .5, step=.01))
interact(lambda t: lines.set_segments([[[0,t],[1,1-t]]]),
     t = FloatSlider(min = 0, max = 1, step=.01))
```

It works fine for the `LineCollection` but changing the parameter for the `PatchCollection` does not make the figure be redrawn. Changing the function for the `PatchCollection` to include `figs.canvas.draw()` fixes the problem, so I thought `PatchCollection.set_paths()` unlike `LineCollection.set_segments()` does not trigger a redraw. <s>However, in the commented line `circles.set_paths()` *does* seem to trigger a redraw.</s> Can somebody explain to me what's going on? If possible I'd like consistent behavior.

Comment: I'm not seeing running your code and then sliding a slider do anything with either slider. Did you leave out how to test it? Plus, it seems you are using outdated approaches to work with ipywidgets and matplotlib. I'm not sure you are basing what you are trying on current documentation, such as [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#flickering-and-jumping-output). That doesn't mean it won't work where you are trying, but it is likely to be brittle and break on further updates of Jupyter and ipywidgets.

Comment: @Wayne No, when I copy the above into a notebook and run it, it will update on the t-sldier but not on the s-slider. What makes you say my approach to ipywidgets is outdated? I would say I use it exactly the way documented on the site you link to. Of course performance might be a concern but in practice isn't and I do want the picture to update "live" (anyway that's not what the question is about).

Comment: I don't know how I missed the t-slider was working. I added my reply concerning how for ipywidgets it is best to start with current examples closes to what you want and adapt them further to my attempt at a working answer because I was writing that and it probably would benefit by the extra space I have in an answer vs a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This gets closer to working as you want, I think:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, CircleCollection, PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider, Layout
%matplotlib notebook
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
lines = LineCollection(np.array([[[0,0],[1,1]]]))
circles = PatchCollection([Circle((.5,.5),.5)])
ax.add_collection(lines)
ax.add_collection(circles)
#lines.set_segments([[[0,1],[1,0]]])
#circles.set_paths([Circle((.5,.5),.1)])
def two(s,t):
    return (circles.set_paths([Circle((.5,.5),s)]),lines.set_segments([[[0,t],[1,1-t]]]))

_ = interact( two,
    s = FloatSlider(value = 0.1, min = 0, max = .5, step=.01),
    t = FloatSlider(value = 0,min = 0, max = 1, step=.01)
)
```

The main adjustment I made is to have one `interact()` function creating the UI and allowing the controlling of the data interactively.
You can combine as many widgets and functions related to each widget as you want; however, the documentation is indicating they should be directed under the one `interact()`.

Based on:

- Mainly [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) where they take about multiple functions
- Combined with mainly [here](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/) that has more examples of multiple widgets and functions, see especially for `def three` in the examples
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198400/8508004) for initial setting

Note I was unclear what you wanted for the initial value of the circle and so you may need to adjust that yourself.

---

---

As for my comments that you aren't following the documentation on using ipywidgets in conjunction with matplotlib that is found under ['Flickering and jumping output'](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#flickering-and-jumping-output). (Note, I think that page is so long or contains some CSS that makes it not directly link to the section it should in my experience and so you may need to scroll down to find it. YMMV.) ....
In particular in that example all the plot defining  handling is built into the single plot function that at which `interact()` is targeted.
I still didn't convert your code to this approach, because maybe you are right that it isn't strictly necessary (as I tried to suggest in my initial comment) and it was more heavy lifting at this time.
I will say I was more able to easily combine many widgets with a plot structuring my code that way, see [here for the code (first example, specifically)](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_adjustableVIAwidgets.ipynb). If you want to see it in action then go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/tree/master) and click `launch binder` and then choose that appropriate notebook from the list there when the sessions starts up, specifically '3D scatter plots customizable via widgets'. Because you are using the classic notebook interface, you'll want to go to the 'Help' menu and choose to launch the classic notebook to switch over trying what I said above. (Note when running there in such sessions, if you want something more like my example or the example from ipywidgets in conjunction to work with something like the `%matplotlib notebook` toolbar gives, you'll want to use `%ipympl`, like stated [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example). Strangely, your code works as is in regards to `%matplotlib notebook` in such sessions without changing to that. My examples on the other hand sort of break under `%matplotlib notebook`. And by 'sort of break', I mean right now when I change to `%matplotlib notebook` and restart the kernel and run the plot code, I don't see the plot but when I adjust a slider I may see the plot again for my example. For the example from the ipywidgets documentation with matplotlib, I see the plot the first time I adjust one of the sliders, but it disappears when I adjust either another time(?). So I suggest `%matplotlib inline or` %matplotlib ipympl` there in that session with any code examples I reference.)

You'll note that if you run my example (or the example from ipywidgets that combines with matplotlib) that you won't don't see any 'artifacts' like the `(None, None)` I see below my edited version if your output. That code example I link to is self-contained and so you should be able to copy the code and try it where you are working to test it behaves well where you are working.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! I thought I had specifically checked that it was not about the order of the two interacts, but perhaps I made a mistake. Anyway I get the idea of one interact and it does make sense.

Comment: Hmmm....maybe it is more complex than the second one being the one that works in the way you had the code. (I removed that and adjusted the language.) I reversed them and it seems the `s` slider works but only after I further toggle the `t` one after toggling the `s` one. Weird. Since that is clunky, I still believe the way the documentation is suggesting to combing things is pointing you to the right route.